# FFMPEG RTSP stream to MPEG4/H264 file using libx264

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, libav, libx264

Heyo folks,

I'm attempting to transcode/remux an RTSP stream in H264 format into a MPEG4 container, containing just the H264 video stream. Basically, webcam output into a MP4 container.

I can get a poorly coded MP4 produced, using this code:

```
// Variables here for demo
AVFormatContext * video_file_output_format = nullptr;
AVFormatContext * rtsp_format_context = nullptr;
AVCodecContext * video_file_codec_context = nullptr;
AVCodecContext * rtsp_vidstream_codec_context = nullptr;
AVPacket packet = {0};
AVStream * video_file_stream = nullptr;
AVCodec * rtsp_decoder_codec = nullptr;
int errorNum = 0, video_stream_index = 0;
std::string outputMP4file = "D:\\somemp4file.mp4";

// begin
AVDictionary * opts = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);

if ((errorNum = avformat_open_input(&rtsp_format_context, uriANSI.c_str(), NULL, &opts)) < 0) {
    errOut << "Connection failed: avformat_open_input failed with error " << errorNum << ":\r\n" << ErrorRead(errorNum);
    TacticalAbort();
    return;
}

rtsp_format_context->max_analyze_duration = 50000;
if ((errorNum = avformat_find_stream_info(rtsp_format_context, NULL)) < 0) {
    errOut << "Connection failed: avformat_find_stream_info failed with error " << errorNum << ":\r\n" << ErrorRead(errorNum);
    TacticalAbort();
    return;
}

video_stream_index = errorNum = av_find_best_stream(rtsp_format_context, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, NULL, 0);

if (video_stream_index < 0) {
    errOut << "Connection in unexpected state; made a connection, but there was no video stream.\r\n"
        "Attempts to find a video stream resulted in error " << errorNum << ": " << ErrorRead(errorNum);
    TacticalAbort();
    return;
}

rtsp_vidstream_codec_context = rtsp_format_context->streams[video_stream_index]->codec;

av_init_packet(&packet);

if (!(video_file_output_format = av_guess_format(NULL, outputMP4file.c_str(),  NULL))) {
    TacticalAbort();
    throw std::exception("av_guess_format");
}

if (!(rtsp_decoder_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(rtsp_vidstream_codec_context->codec_id))) {
    errOut << "Connection failed: connected, but avcodec_find_decoder returned null.\r\n"
        "Couldn't find codec with an AV_CODEC_ID value of " << rtsp_vidstream_codec_context->codec_id << ".";
    TacticalAbort();
    return;
}

video_file_format_context = avformat_alloc_context();
video_file_format_context->oformat = video_file_output_format;

if (strcpy_s(video_file_format_context->filename, sizeof(video_file_format_context->filename), outputMP4file.c_str())) {
    errOut << "Couldn't open video file: strcpy_s failed with error " << errno << ".";
    std::string log = errOut.str();
    TacticalAbort();
    throw std::exception("strcpy_s");
}

if (!(video_file_encoder_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(video_file_output_format->video_codec))) {
    TacticalAbort();
    throw std::exception("avcodec_find_encoder");
}

// MARKER ONE

if (!outputMP4file.empty() &&
    !(video_file_output_format->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE) &&
    (errorNum = avio_open2(&video_file_format_context->pb, outputMP4file.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, nullptr, &opts)) < 0) {
    errOut << "Couldn't open video file \"" << outputMP4file << "\" for writing : avio_open2 failed with error " << errorNum << ": " << ErrorRead(errorNum);
    TacticalAbort();
    return;
}

// Create stream in MP4 file
if (!(video_file_stream = avformat_new_stream(video_file_format_context, video_file_encoder_codec))) {
    TacticalAbort();
    return;
}

AVCodecContext * video_file_codec_context = video_file_stream->codec;

// MARKER TWO

// error -22/-21 in avio_open2 if this is skipped
if ((errorNum = avcodec_copy_context(video_file_codec_context, rtsp_vidstream_codec_context)) != 0) {
    TacticalAbort();
    throw std::exception("avcodec_copy_context");
}

//video_file_codec_context->codec_tag = 0;

/*
// MARKER 3 - is this not needed? Examples suggest not.
if ((errorNum = avcodec_open2(video_file_codec_context, video_file_encoder_codec, &opts)) < 0)
{
    errOut << "Couldn't open video file codec context: avcodec_open2 failed with error " << errorNum << ": " << ErrorRead(errorNum);
    std::string log = errOut.str();
    TacticalAbort();
    throw std::exception("avcodec_open2, video file");
}*/

//video_file_format_context->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_GENPTS;
if (video_file_format_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
{
    video_file_codec_context->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}

if ((errorNum = avformat_write_header(video_file_format_context, &opts)) < 0) {
    errOut << "Couldn't open video file: avformat_write_header failed with error " << errorNum << ":\r\n" << ErrorRead(errorNum);
    std::string log = errOut.str();
    TacticalAbort();
    return;
}
```

However, there are several issues:

1. I can't pass any x264 options to the output file. The output H264 matches the input H264's profile/level - switching cameras to a different model switches H264 level.
2. The timing of the output file is off, noticeably.
3. The duration of the output file is off, massively. A few seconds of footage becomes hours, although playtime doesn't match. (FWIW, I'm using VLC to play them.)

**Passing x264 options**

If I manually increment PTS per packet, and set DTS equal to PTS, it plays too fast, ~2-3 seconds' worth of footage in one second playtime, and duration is hours long. The footage also blurs past several seconds, about 10 seconds' footage in a second.

If I let FFMPEG decide (with or without GENPTS flag), the file has a variable frame rate (probably as expected), but it plays the whole file in an instant and has a long duration too (over forty hours for a few seconds). The duration isn't "real", as the file plays in an instant.

At Marker One, I try to set the profile by passing options to `avio_open2`. The options are simply ignored by libx264. I've tried:

```
av_dict_set(&opts, "vprofile", "main", 0);
av_dict_set(&opts, "profile", "main", 0); // error, missing '('
// FF_PROFILE_H264_MAIN equals 77, so I also tried
av_dict_set(&opts, "vprofile", "77", 0); 
av_dict_set(&opts, "profile", "77", 0);
```

It does seem to read the profile setting, but it doesn't use them. At Marker Two, I tried to set it after the `avio_open2`, before `avformat_write_header` .

```
// I tried all 4 av_dict_set from earlier, passing it to avformat_write_header.
// None had any effect, they weren't consumed.
av_opt_set(video_file_codec_context, "profile", "77", 0);
av_opt_set(video_file_codec_context, "profile", "main", 0);
video_file_codec_context->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_MAIN;
av_opt_set(video_file_codec_context->priv_data, "profile", "77", 0);
av_opt_set(video_file_codec_context->priv_data, "profile", "main", 0);
```

Messing with privdata made the program unstable, but I was trying anything at that point.
I'd like to solve issue 1 with passing settings, since I imagine it'd bottleneck any attempt to solve issues 2 or 3.

I've been fiddling with this for the better part of a month now. I've been through dozens of documentation, Q&As, examples. It doesn't help that quite a few are outdated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, firstly, I wasn't using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org), but a fork of ffmpeg called [libav](http://libav.org/). Not to be confused, ffmpeg is more recent, and libav was used in some distributions of Linux.

### Compiling for Visual Studio

Once I upgraded to the main branch, I had to compile it manually again, since I was using it in Visual Studio and the only static libraries are G++, so linking doesn't work nicely.

The official guide is https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC.
First, compiling as such works fine:
Ensure VS is in PATH. Your PATH should read **in this order**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX.0\VC\bin
D:\MinGW\msys64\mingw32\bin  
D:\MinGW\msys64\usr\bin  
D:\MinGW\bin
```

Then run Visual Studio x86 Native Tools prompt. Should be in your Start Menu.
In the CMD, run
`(your path to MinGW)\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -full-path`
In the created MinGW window, run:
`$ cd /your dev path/`
`$ git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg`
After about five minutes you'll have the FFMPEG source in the subfolder ffmpeg.
Access the source via:
`$ cd ffmpeg`
Then run:
`$ which link`
if it doesn't provide the VS path from PATH, but usr/link or usr/bin/link, rename similarly:
`$ mv /usr/bin/link.exe /usr/bin/msys-link.exe`
If it does skip the $ mv step.

Finally, run this command:
`$ ./configure --toolchain=msvc` and whatever other cmdlines you want
(you can see commandlines via `./configure --help`)
It may appear inactive for a long time. Once it's done you'll get a couple pages of output.

Then run:
`$ make`
`$ make install`

Note for static builds (configure with `--enable-static`), although you get Windows static lib files, it'll produce them with extension *.a files. Just rename to .lib.
(you can use cmd: `ren *.a *.lib`)

### Using FFMPEG

To just **copy** from FFMPEG RTSP to a file, using source profile, level etc, just use:

1. read network frame `av_read_frame(rtsp_format_context)`
2. pass to MP4 `av_write_frame(video_file_format_context)`

You don't need to open a AVCodecContext, a decoder or encoder; just `avformat_open_input`, and the video file AVFormatContext and AVIOContext.

If you want to re-encode, you have to:

1. read network frame
   `av_read_frame(rtsp_format_context)`
2. pass packet to decoder
   `avcodec_send_packet(rtsp_decoder_context)`
3. read frames from decoder (in loop)
   `avcodec_receive_frame(rtsp_decoder_context)`
4. send each decoded frame to encoder
   `avcodec_send_frame(video_file_encoder_context)`
5. read packets from encoder (in loop)
   `avcodec_receive_packet(video_file_encoder_context)`
6. send each encoded packet to output video   `av_write_frame(video_file_format_context)`

### Some gotchas

- Copy out the width, height, and pixel format manually. For H264 it's YUV420P.
  As example, for level 3.1, profile high:

  ```
    AVCodecParameters * video_file_codec_params = video_file_stream->codecpar;
    video_file_codec_params->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_HIGH;
    video_file_codec_params->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    video_file_codec_params->level = 31;
    video_file_codec_params->width = rtsp_vidstream->codecpar->width;
    video_file_codec_params->height = rtsp_vidstream->codecpar->height;
  ```
- libx264 accepts a H264 preset via the opts parameter in `avcodec_open2`. Example for "veryfast" preset:

  ```
    AVDictionary * mydict;
    av_dict_set(&mydict, "preset", "veryfast", 0);
    avcodec_open2(video_file_encoder_context, video_file_encoder_codec, &opts)
    // avcodec_open2 returns < 0 for errors.
    // Recognised options will be removed from the mydict variable.
    // If all are recognised, mydict will be NULL.
  ```
- Output timing is a volatile thing. Use this before ``.

  ```
    video_file_stream->avg_frame_rate = rtsp_vidstream->avg_frame_rate;
    video_file_stream->r_frame_rate = rtsp_vidstream->r_frame_rate;
    video_file_stream->time_base = rtsp_vidstream->time_base;
    video_file_encoder_context->time_base = rtsp_vidstream_codec_context->time_base;
    // Decreasing GOP size for more seek positions doesn't end well.
    // libx264 forces the new GOP size.
    video_file_encoder_context->gop_size = rtsp_vidstream_codec_context->gop_size;
    if ((errorNum = avcodec_open2(video_file_encoder_context,...)) < 0) {
        // an error...
    }
  ```
- H264 may write at double-speed to the file, so playback is doubly fast. To change this, go manual with encoded packets' timing:

  ```
    packet->pts = packet->dts = frameNum++;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(packet, video_file_encoder_context->time_base, video_file_stream->time_base);
    packet->pts *= 2;
    packet->dts *= 2;
    av_interleaved_write_frame(video_file_format_context, packet)
    // av_interleaved_write_frame returns < 0 for errors.
  ```

  Note we switch `av_write_frame` to `av_interleaved_write_frame`, and set both PTS and DTS. `frameNum` should be a int64_t, and should start from 0 (although that's not required).

  Also note the `av_rescale_ts` call's parameters are the video file encoder context, and the video file stream - RTSP isn't involved.
- VLC media player won't play H.264 streams encoded with an FPS of 4 or lower.
  So if your RTSP streams are showing the first decoded frame and never progressing, or showing pure green until the video ends, make sure your FPS is high enough. (that's VLC v2.2.4)

Comment: would you be able to provide a source code sample for this?

Comment: @CristianToma I did go into quite a bit of detail already, what do you need help on?

Comment: It doesn't work for me with the changes you suggested and because you offered to send the source code, I said I might ask if you can

Comment: @CristianToma I don't have the source public on GitHub yet, so I can't post the full source. It has several variations over time as well that will confuse the issue. I'd be happy to help you through whatever error you have, though. What part isn't working?